# Javascript works on 1 web host but not the other

Tags: javascript, html

So I have 2 websites, 1 for developing and other for the main website. I have a checkbox that unlocks a button on the website, this checkbox works on the developing one but not the real one and I'm unsure as to why. The error code is Uncaught reference error Togglelink is not defined.

Here's my code

```
    function toggleLink(checkBox) {
  var link = document.getElementById("agreeLink");

  if (checkBox.checked)
    link.style.display = "inline";
  else
    link.style.display = "none";
}
```

And

```
<form class="center" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <label for="terms_and_conditions">(<span style="color: red">REQUIERED to unlock Buy Now button</span>)I have read and agree to all the terms and conditions:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" value="agreeCheckbox" onchange="toggleLink(this);" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="8346JDMASY5Z6">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Choose an amount">Choose an amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="os0">
          <option value="1000 Cash Points =">1000 Cash Points = $10.00 USD</option>
          <option value="2000 Cash Points =">2000 Cash Points = $20.00 USD</option>
          <option value="3300 Cash Points =">3300 Cash Points = $30.00 USD</option>
          <option value="6000 Cash Points =">6000 Cash Points = $50.00 USD</option>
          <option value="13000 Cash Points =">13000 Cash Points = $100.00 USD</option>
          <option value="28000 Cash Points =">28000 Cash Points = $200.00 USD</option>
          <option value="45000 Cash Points =">45000 Cash Points = $300.00 USD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="image" id="agreeLink" style="display:none;" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

Comment: Can you share the 'main website'?

Comment: @gunwin http://aquaragnarok.com/?module=core&action=donate this is the non working one, http://aquaragnarokonline.club/?module=core&action=donate is the working one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You javascript appears to be escaped, using a [CDATASection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection)

Change from this:

```js
              <![CDATA[
              function toggleLink(checkBox)
              {
              var link = document.getElementById("agreeLink");

              if (checkBox.checked)
              link.style.display = "inline";
              else
              link.style.display = "none";
              }
              ]]>
```

To this:

```js
              function toggleLink(checkBox)
              {
              var link = document.getElementById("agreeLink");

              if (checkBox.checked)
              link.style.display = "inline";
              else
              link.style.display = "none";
              }
```

Comment: thank you for the help, I'll try this when I get home